Errors not visible in Text Editor in Visual Studio
In Visual Studio 2022 my errors aren't visible in the Text Editor.
They are detected by IntelliSense, since they appear in the Error List, but the squiggles in the Text Editor don't show. The red dot in the scrollbar doesn't show either. Normally I can also double click on the error in the Error List to automatically go to the error, but that also stopped working.
When I check the option in Options => Text Editor => C# => Advanced => Display diagnostics inline; error are displayed at the end of the line, but without the squiggles and not in the scroll bar.

I've noticed that in the xaml text editor everything does still work (squiggles, scroll bar, clicking from the error list, ...).
So far I have:

Checked that'Show error squiggles' is checked in Options => Text Editor => General
Restarted Visual Studio
Repaired Visual Studio
Updated Visual Studio
Tried making a new project, but it's the same with all projects
Deleted the hidden .vs-folder for the solution

Edit:
New tries as suggested by the replies:

Running VS in safe mode => I got a bunch of errors that packages couldn't load and eventually my projects in the solution can't load

As suggested; ReSharper is likely the culprit. It was installed, but kept crashing, so VS suggested disabling the extension, which I did. That was around the time the problem began. When I looked now, it wasn't only Disabled, but wasn't installed anymore. Now I tried repairing, uninstalling, reinstalling, uninstalling again,... I looked into the suggested option Hide all Visual Studio squiggles and file health indicator, but this doesn't exist in my case (maybe a difference in versions?). I also cleared the ReSharper cache, but nothing worked.
I tried resetting all the Visual Studio Settings, but got an error: [code 5465]. The internet didn't provide me with much of an explanation about that.
Eventually ended up uninstalling VS with the InstallCleanup-Tool and reinstalling it, but even that didn't fix my problem

Any other suggestions?

One thing you didn't mention trying was starting the IDE in safe mode with all extensions disabled. Also try different project types. Also, you can try to remove Visual Studio entirely and reinstall it. The default uninstall and repair options leave large amounts of IDE components behind

If the red squiggles don't show in your Text Editor with Show error squiggles is checked, it could be some reasons. Please check the following to see if these help.
1.Since it works fine in xaml text editor but not c#, it could be that extensions installed overrides the functionality. For example, if you installed extension Resharper,please uncheck the highlighted setting.

You can also start IDE in safe mode as @Aluan noted in the above comment.This switch prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts, allowing stable execution.
devenv /SafeMode

2.Please make sure  not to open c# project file  by  "Open folder".
3.Please try to Rest all settings.
4.If the issue persists, please use this tool InstallCleanup.exe to uninstall your VS Instances.(Note: It will remove all instances installed on your machine).For more informaiton, please refer to Remove all with InstallCleanup.exe
UPDATE
manually remove VS
Manually delete any cache folder you previously installed to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
%programdata%\Microsoft\visualstudio\packages
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages
%Temp%

Delete the setup registry key, which was set when you installed VS for the first time:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
Note: Please backup before deleting.


I tried your suggestions, but without success. I edited my original post with my findings.

Try to uninstall VS manually then reinstall the latest version. Please see the update. Besides could you share a screenshot that  red squiggles  does not show up?

Tried the manual uninstall, but also no success. I added a screenshot to the original post. In the screenshot the option 'Display diagnostics inline' is active, but no squiggles, nothing in the scroll bar and double clicking in the error list is still not possible. Maybe something from ReSharper is left behind somewhere?

An abnormal behavior. Are you able to find files related to  ReSharper   in your extensions location:%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Visual Studio version>\Extensions\,
Visual Studio installation folder>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ ? If yes, try to delete them.

I deleted both when I uninstalled it manually last time

It seems a ReSharper extension issue. Please try to report this issue on ReSharper community to get their professional support.
